# Setting loader globally in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an instance file where i get the token and authorization headers

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
(config) => {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
return config;
},
(error) => {
return Promise.reject(error);
}
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Can i set the loader here so that when each http request is fired the loader works,If so how can i set that ?

Comment: "loader" or "headers"? Does your solution not work?

Comment: I need to set a loader for each apis such that when each api loads the loader should work

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default class FetchAPI {
  constructor() {
    this.getXX=async param=>{
     return await fetch(param, 'post', "/API/getXX");
    }
  //============================================================
    const axiosInstance = axios.create();
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    const fetch = async (data, method, url, responseType, headers) => {
      const requestObj = {
        url,
        method,
        responseType,
        headers,
        [method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "params" : "data"]: data,
      };
      const response = await axiosInstance(requestObj); // use the created instance
       return response.data;
    }
  }
}
```

To Call it,

```js
let fetcAPI=new FetchAPI();
let xx=await fetchAPI.getXX();
```